# Match Excel Date Range with Day of Week

Tags: excel, vba, date, dynamic

I have a expense form with a departure and return date. I would like to match all dates between the departure date and return, inclusive, to the day of the week and then populate that date under the appropriate day of the week that exists in another part of the form. 
I've provided an example screenshot of what I'm trying to populate and what I'd like it to look like.

I've tried index/match, creating tables to allow the "in between" dates to expand automatically, linking to a date table in powerpivot, etc. and keep failing. I haven't tried an VBA yet.

Your thoughts are much appreciated!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's plenty of ways to do this. Along similar lines to what you have tried, I got this. It works as per your screenshot and also tested with different dates below:

[image]

---

**Formulas**.

E1: `=B1` 
E2: `=E1+1` and drag down
F1: `=IF(E1<=$B$2,TEXT(E1,"ddd"),"")` and drag down 
B12: `=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$E$7,MATCH(B11,$F$1:$F$7,0)),"")` and drag across

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. I wasn't using Index/Match appropriately. I really  appreciate your help!